# styling radio button with css doesn't work

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to style a radio button using just css, but i can't figure out why it does not work:

HTML

```
<input type="radio">
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"]{
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vNmLe/

Comment: it's because its appearance is still a default radio, you can set `appearance` to `none` (only for webkit-based browsers) and style it from scratch. For other browsers we need more trick. It's fairly complicated to a CSS beginner I think.

Comment: do you know how to do it for another browsers? doesn't matter if it uses js or whatever

Comment: check out my answer about customizing radio button here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181319/customizing-radio-buttons/23184315#23184315 You would learn something from the demo in there.

Comment: @KingKing thanks but now i have another problem, when i have multiple radio buttons and add style it let me mark all radio buttons (normally, i can only mark one of them) do you know why?

Comment: it's because your radio buttons are not grouped into a group, to group some radio buttons, you have to set the same name (`name` attribute) to all the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons, checkboxes and selects can't be styled very well in a cross-browser fashion using only CSS. You'll need some extra markup and a little javascript.

One technique is to wrap the input inside a div and set the input's opacity to 0. You position the input inside of the wrapping div so that it fills the entire space.

HTML:

```
<div class="faux-radio" data-group="radio-test">
    <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio-test">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;    
}

.faux-radio {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    border: 1px solid #a6a6a6;
    border-radius: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.faux-radio.selected:after {
    content: '';
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #666;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
}

label {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

With this technique you get your own style and still get all of the standard input behavior. But you have extra markup for every form element. And you'll need to add some javascript to provide the visual feedback users expect when clicking form elemens.

Here's a quick radio button example with js included: http://jsfiddle.net/xevw3/17/