# how do I customize/change the default outline of a radio button?

Tags: css

I've got a client requesting that the currently light-grey circular outline border of the radio button be made bolder/darker black. I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

[image]

```
 <input type="radio" value="original" name="addressInfo" id="radio_original">
```

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452276/styling-radio-button-with-css-doesnt-work)

Comment: Is the part with the text:`Use address listed below` a `<label>`? If so, add that to your post code example, if not, are you permitted to add and/or move a `<label>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 1px solid gray;

input[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before {
  background: darkgray;
```

or something similar.

Comment: These rules don't apply to the HTML the OP posted as they aren't using adjacent elements (what the `~` combinator is for)

Answer (score 0):

I ask to see this decision as an example for stylization.

```
<input type="radio" value="original" name="addressInfo" id="radio_original">
```

CSS

```
#radio_original{
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
  display: none;
}
label{
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#radio_original:checked+label{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

You can solve this problem with tag label.